# Getting error: DeprecationWarning: Buffer(), Only when deploying the website with IISNode

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, child-process, deprecation-warning

I made this short code to open a file on the server (.exe) using Node.js and child_process.

```
const express = require('express');
const ks = require('node-key-sender')
app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render(__dirname + "/views/main.ejs");
});

app.get('/api/start', (req, res) => {
    var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
    console.log("starting");
    require('child_process').spawnSync('start', ['hlds.exe.lnk'], {shell: true})
    ks.sendKey("@10").then(res.send("OK")).catch("ERROR");
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
// app.listen("3000");
```

The code works just fine when it runs locally, but when I deploy the site (using IISNode) I get this error:

```
(node:2368) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

I've tried searching for the Buffer() functions in the child_process library but couldn't find any usage of the function.

Comment: `child_process` is a built-in module, the warning isn't coming from there. Most likely from `node-key-sender` or other package you're not showing

Comment: Got it.
but now when the app is deployed the: require('child_process').spawnSync('start', ['hlds.exe.lnk'], {shell: true})

isn't doing it's job.

any ideas?